# Java - DoublyLinkedList Iterator implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

I have implemented a DoublyLinkedList, as follows:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {

protected static class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> prev;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
        element = e;
        prev = p;
        next = n;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        next = n;
    }
}

protected Node<E> header;
protected Node<E> trailer;
private int size = 0;

public DoublyLinkedList() {
    header = new Node<>(null, null, null);
    trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);
    header.setNext(trailer);
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement an iterator and this is the solution I came up with:

```
private class DLLIterator implements Iterator<E> {

    private Node<E> cursor = header;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != null;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException("No next element.");
        E element = cursor.getElement();
        cursor = cursor.getNext();
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported.");
    }
}
```

It seems correct, but I'm having a lot of doubts about the hasNext() method and the initial cursor assignment. Shouldn't it be

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor.getNext() != null;
}
```

?

Otherwise, it seems to me that the iterator will get me two null elements, trying to fetch them from the header and trailer. Should I change the method?

Comment: This looks fine to me. Changing the implementation would just complicate things, e.g. what if the header passed in is null? ```hasNext``` would trow NPE. It wouldn't return any null elements either, since it checks if the current Node is null before returning it (unless, of course, that Node contains null).

Comment: But wouldn't this give me a null element on the first iteration since it starts on the header?

Comment: That depends on what ```header``` is in the doubly linked list. I'd expect it to be a reference to the first Node/element or null if the list is empty.

Comment: I should've clarified that, header is simply a pointer to the first element. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jorn Vernee's comment contains the right answer:

> Changing the implementation would just complicate things, e.g. what if
>   the header passed in is null? hasNext would trow NPE. It wouldn't
>   return any null elements either, since it checks if the current Node
>   is null before returning it (unless, of course, that Node contains
>   null).